# SQLPLUS how to use Edit and save a sql script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am taking a database class and we are using oracle sqlplus. I have worked with many different database management systems before and several different flavors of SQL but I am having trouble doing something incredibly simple it would seem. I am trying to use the editor in sqlplus by typing into sqlplus SQL> ED, which works but then I can't find any way to save the file once I am done writing my script. I'm sure this is incredibly simple but it's hard to find anything online that tells how to save a file once you are in the editor. I am just trying to copy and paste my script in from notepad basically and save it using the editor so I can run it to create several tables at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save it as `script.sql` and then run it using `sqlplus @script.sql`.

For example `echo "SELECT * FROM table" > script.sql` and then `sqlplus user/pass@db @script.sql`.

Comment: Yeah but my question is how do I save it after I have it typed in the editor? I have tried Save test.sql, nothing happens so I am not sure how else to save from the editor

Comment: It sounds like your environment has `vi` set as the default editor, in which case you want to use `:wq` to write and quit.

Comment: Also note that there is no such thing as an editor within SQL. It simply opens your default editor. It would be the same as doing `vi script.sql` outside of SQL.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it seems that it was set to vi for the default editor. Is there a way to change it to a more user friendly editor?

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer. The variable _EDITOR, may be used to setup a preferred text editor, for example, define vi as the SQL*Plus editor:

DEFINE _EDITOR = vi

or define Metapad.exe as the SQL*Plus editor:

DEFINE _EDITOR = Metapad.exe

Include an editor definition like the above in your user profile (login.sql) or site profile ($ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql) so that it is always enabled when you start SQL*Plus.